# Visual studio change datetype in reports by itself

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm creating a report in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. As a source data I use a SQL Server table. I have there two columns with datetype "BIT" (values 0 or 1), which servers as boolean (true/false). However, visual studio in report preview always put word "true" or "false" by itself. I don't know this. I need to get 1 or 0, instead "true" or "false"

I tried to convert source data and convert BIT to INT by

```
CONVERT(INT, col1)
```

However I have always there true/false word. How can I edit that?

PS: That's my very first report ever, so I really don't know.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Set an expression into the cell of your report: 
=IIF(Fields!**YOURFIELDNAME**.Value = true, "1", "0")

Answer (score 0):

Cast your code in query level.

```
Select cast(BitValue as int) AS columnname from Table
```

Use field `columnname` in your report.